# How do I extract <b> tag from a div using rvest?

Tags: html, r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I have this html:

```
<div class="monty">album: <b>And Now For Something Completely Different</b> (1998)</div>
```

I'm currently using this xpath to find it:

```
    for_monty <- rvest::html_node(for_html_code, xpath = "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[11]/div[1]/b")
```

But not all pages have this div number so sometimes it doesn't scrape anything. The only permanent class is `monty` and I would like to pull only the `<b>` tag from inside that div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though your xpath should be `//div[@class='monty']/b`

We can try this as a full reprex on your own snippet:

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2

html <- "<div class=\"monty\">album: <b>And Now For Something Completely Different</b> (1998)</div>"

read_html(html) %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "//div[@class='monty']/b")
#> {xml_nodeset (1)}
#> [1] <b>And Now For Something Completely Different</b>
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Oh wow, thank you so much! This works perfectly. Is there anywhere I can read up more on these kind of paths and how to make them? I couldn't find how to write this so I had to ask here. Or do people generally use some chrome extension (or something) to generate these?

Comment: @Aman no, I find using the Chrome or Firefox extensions that give you xpaths tend to use indexing, which makes them much more vulnerable to minor changes in html structure. You can get an introduction to xpath [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp), and there are lots of great questions and answers right here on Stack Overflow for more complicated stuff.